# FancyBox steals content and doesn't put it back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have fancybox triggered on a link that loads content from a hidden div.

**If I close the fancybox and click the link again, it loads up blank the second time around**

Here's my code:

```
$.fancybox({
    content: $target
});
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: You don't provide to much information. Are you using Fancybox v.1.3.x? if so, there are known issues (and workaround) about inline content that you can check here: http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fab7b6d81a173b33/ . On the other hand, if your inline content (fancybox v1.3.x) is an (inline) iframe, then check also this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/feec524b4c0199bc

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of bother with other people's light boxes, issues similar to yours, and other issues with not displaying content and such.

This quick bit of code creates the same as the fancybox plugin (essentially), this is what I use all the time, and its cross browser compatible and easy to debug and change when your content doesn't fit or comes out screwy or anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('a.clickme').click(function(){

            // this creates an overlay
            var theOverlay = $('<table class="overlayTable"><tr><td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;padding:0"></td></tr></table>')
                .click(function(){ $(document).unbind('keyup'); $(this).remove(); });

        // this creates the white "inner" box
            $('<div></div>')
                .attr('id','insideContent')
                .css({
                    'display':'inline-block',
                    'background':'#fff',
                    'padding':'20px'
                })
                .append('<p>Some content here... you can load anything you want - or copy it from another div if you want...</p>')
                .appendTo($('body'))
                .wrap(theOverlay)
                .click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });

            $(document).bind('keyup', function(e){
            // this binds the esc key to close the overlay
                if(e.keyCode==27) { $(document).unbind('keyup'); $('table.overlayTable').remove(); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
.overlayTable {
    background: url("url/to/transparent/png/for/overlay/background.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;

    height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 999;
    left: 0; position: fixed; top: 0;

}
</style>
```

Feel free to make it into a plugin or similar. As you're just filling a div with content you can put any HTML or anything in there you want.

You can also add your own touches, such as the close button (all it needs to do is call `$('table.overlayTable').remove();`).